# Sett up multuihost Hyperledger-Fabric environment with Hyperledger-Celllo

Tags: azure, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My current setup is I already have VMs in azure cloud running with ubuntu on it I need to setup multihost Hyperledger fabric network on that I am trying that with cello project
I have created runhosts.tpl in *cello/src/agent/ansible/run/* with details of public IP and private IP when I try to run `ansible-playbook -vvv -i run/runhosts -e "mode=apply env=azure env_type=flanneld ansible_ssh_user=hyperchain" initcluster.yml` I am getting this error

```
TASK [Retrive golang binary and unpackage it] **********************************
task path: /home/rtcin/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/hyperchain/cello/src/agent/ansible/roles/env_flanneld/fastinitnode/tasks/apply.yml:48
<xx.xx.xx..209> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: hyperchain
<xx.xx.xx..209> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=hyperchain -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/rtcin/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt xx.xx.xx..209 '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1516608420.49-127169744664202 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1516608420.49-127169744664202 )" )'
<xx.xx.xx..209> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: hyperchain
<xx.xx.xx..209> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=hyperchain -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/rtcin/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt xx.xx.xx..209 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-mpgibfkxyljaxvrujpbtptppmjpaxtht; rc=flag; [ -r /opt ] || rc=2; [ -f /opt ] || rc=1; [ -d /opt ] && rc=3; python -V 2>/dev/null || rc=4; [ x"$rc" != "xflag" ] && echo "${rc}  "/opt && exit 0; (python -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'import hashlib; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = hashlib.sha1();
afile = open("'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/opt'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'", "rb")
buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
while len(buf) > 0:
    hasher.update(buf)
    buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
afile.close()
print(hasher.hexdigest())'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' 2>/dev/null) || (python -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'import sha; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = sha.sha();
afile = open("'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/opt'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'", "rb")
buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
while len(buf) > 0:
    hasher.update(buf)
    buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
afile.close()
print(hasher.hexdigest())'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' 2>/dev/null) || (echo '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'0  '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/opt)'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"''"'"''
<xx.xx.xx..209> PUT /home/rtcin/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/hyperchain/cello/src/agent/ansible/roles/env_flanneld/https:/storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz TO /home/hyperchain/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1516608420.49-127169744664202/source
fatal: [xx.xx.xx..209]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! file or module does not exist: /home/rtcin/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/hyperchain/cello/src/agent/ansible/roles/env_flanneld/https:/storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz"}
```

Can anyone help me in using cello project. From the errors in last 2lines I can understand URL is considered as file path